# Iterator method with LinkedList

Tags: java, collections

I have recently started learning java, and would be thankful if anyone could help me with this.
The values get printed when I use for loop. However, with the Iterator method, it keeps looping forever. I am not sure what's going wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList ls = new LinkedList();
    ls.add(0);
    ls.add("Apple");
    ls.add(34.5);
    System.out.println(ls);
    for(Object e :ls) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    
    Iterator i = ls.iterator();  
    while(i.hasNext()); {
      System.out.println(i.next());
    }        
}
```

Comment: `while(i.hasNext());` Remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the semi-colon at the end of `while(i.hasNext());`, it means the body of the `while` loop is an empty statement, leading to an infinite loop, so just remove that.